# Correct way to reference up to date Vue delimiters in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm authoring a component for Vue.js applications and have run into a problem where if the delimiters are changed in the application code, the plugin template obviously does not work correctly (this was picked up immediately because we alter the Vue delimiters to not conflict with Twig template tokens).

My component for the sake of example looks like:

```
Vue.component('example', {
    template: 'Something with {{ normal_delimiters }}'
});
```

Assuming some standard `<script>` includes in an application:

```
<script src="path/to/vue.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/my-component.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/application.js"></script>
```

Referencing the `Vue.config.delimiters` option in the component code will yield the default (`{{ }}`) as they aren't changed until the application code farther down the page.

There are a few roads I could invest in looking at like using the `ready` handler on the component and somehow updating the template string, forcing the delimiters to be changed as the first piece of JavaScript in the page (very bad experience) etc, but thought I'd ask if there was a "correct" way to do this.

---

It looks like a solution to this was [discussed but abandoned](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/918).

---

It doesn't look like accessing or modifying `this.$template` inside any of the [lifecycle hooks](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) has any effect.

Comment: According to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/src/entries/web-runtime-with-compiler.js#L57, in Vue 2.0's web compiler it might be possible to do this by setting $options.delimiters = [open, close] on a Component. Untested though and I doubt this works with vue-loader, vueify, and similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of Vue 2 solves this problem entirely by having the delimiters configurable on a per-component basis.